# How can I fix “Cannot read value of type Vector2 from composite” error in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, movement, input, jumping

I'm making a 2D game with Unity using the new Input System. I used `spriteRenderer.flipX` to flip the player but since it is made of three parts (body and two eyes), the `spriteRenderer` didn't work. Also, I couldn't convert them to a single sprite because I need the eyes in order to animate them. So, I decided to use `transform.localscale` for flipping and change `movementInput` value from a float to a Vector2. The problem is that when I press the arrow or AD keys to move the character, an error pops up saying "Cannot read value of type Vector2 from composite". This error is from `InputActionState` which is a long and complicated code related to the new Input System. Also, getting input from gamepad causes the same error. I don't know what does this error mean and how can I fix it. Now, the player can jump but it can't move or flip. You can see the code, the error and my action map down below.

This is my Player Controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed, jumpSpeed;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask ground;
    private PlayerActionControls playerActionControls;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private PolygonCollider2D pol;
    private Animator animator;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private Vector2 movementInput;

private void Awake() {
       
    playerActionControls = new PlayerActionControls();  
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
    pol = GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();   
      
   }

private void OnEnable() {

    playerActionControls.Enable();

   }

 private void OnDisable() {

    playerActionControls.Disable();
   }

 void Start()
   {
     playerActionControls.Land.Jump.performed += ctx => Jump(ctx.ReadValue<float>());

    }   

private void Jump(float val) {
       if (val == 1 && IsGrounded()) {
           rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpSpeed), ForceMode2D.Impulse);       
       }
   }
     

private bool IsGrounded() {
  
       Vector2 topLeftPoint = transform.position;
       topLeftPoint.x -= pol.bounds.extents.x;
       topLeftPoint.y += pol.bounds.extents.y;

       Vector2 bottomRightPoint = transform.position;
       bottomRightPoint.x += pol.bounds.extents.x;
       bottomRightPoint.y -= pol.bounds.extents.y;

       return Physics2D.OverlapArea(topLeftPoint, bottomRightPoint, ground);
   }
     void FixedUpdate()
   {    
       if(facingRight == false && movementInput.x > 0){       
           Flip();
       } else if (facingRight == true && movementInput.x < 0){        
           Flip();    
       }
   }
   void Flip(){
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
   }
  
   void Update()
   {
      movementInput = playerActionControls.Land.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();
       
       Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;  // This was a Vector3 but since I got the error  "Operator '+=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2", I changed it to a Vector2.
       currentPosition += movementInput * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       transform.position = currentPosition;
     
   }
}
```

This is the error I get when I want to move the player.
[image]

This is my action map.

[image]

Comment: Your movement controls look like they are only left-right, not up-down. If that's the case, perhaps the Move input is using a single axis (meaning it will only have a float value) rather than a 2-axis Vector2 value?

Comment: @Kevin  They are only left-right because I don't need up-down for this 2D game. Before this, I was using just a `Left Stick` binding but its problem was that the left stick could move the player to up and down and it made a weird bouncing. I hope this answers your question if not, please tell me to give more information about this.

Comment: So it sounds like you're trying to read a two-axis input when you only need one axis. Try getting a <float> instead of a <Vector2>

Comment: @Kevin This was a float but I changed it to a Vector2 because I wanted to get flipping working. I had to use sprite renderer component if I changed it to a float which was not what I wanted. Also, I wrote a comment in the code about  `Vector2 currentPosition = transform.position;` and this problem might be due to that. This was a Vector3 but I changed it to a Vector2 because I got an error saying that "operator is ambiguous on operands of type Vector 3 and Vector2". Can this be related to the current problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps since I have never used the new input system, but googling the error I see people have similar issues caused by Unitys auto generated files. Most people said this was fixed by regenerating the action map, whatever that means. It seems to be an error that happens when you change the inputs type (in your case I'm guessing float to Vector2. Mostly likely if you ask for your old input type you will still get a result of that type instead of the new Vector2 type).

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson Thanks for your reply! I tried regenerating the action map before (deleted it and make it again) but it didn't help. About changing inputs, you're right. I'm trying to change it because I wanted to have a working flipping system. If I could write the flipping code without using Vector2, I would definitely do it. In general, I'm struggling with the new input system for a long time and still have problems with it. I was using the old input system for a while and had a complete player controller but since I wanted to support gamepad, I had to change the input.

Comment: @Ali This is going to sound either really dumb or really obvious, but when you changed from float to Vector2 for your controls, did you right click your "Move" action and click "Add 2D Vector Composite" or are these just regular old float bindings? Just comparing my input inspect and yours, mine shows the composites in blue and the individual bindings in pink. In yours it's just individual bindings in blue (which makes me think these are still just float bindings).

Comment: @Ali My point is, you can't use `ReadValue<Vector2>` if the actual value from the input is a float. You may need to adjust your input settings. I don't understand what you're saying about needing to use sprites with a float or being unable to have a flipping system (or even what you mean by "flipping")

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson I changed the value from float to Vector2 from my player controller code specifically the flipping, which was a float. I didn't add "2D Vector Composite" but I used "1D Axis Composite" before making my current action map. Your action map looks like that because you probably have added 1D Axis or  2D Vector Composite but mine is just made of bindings.

Comment: @Kevin I commented `ReadValue<Vector2>` for now. I've explained about the sprites and flipping in my question.  What I mean by "flipping" is if  the player is moving to the right, it should be  facing right and if it's moving to the left, it should be facing to left.The problem is from the player which is made from several parts. For implementing flipping, I just know two options. One of them was using sprite renderer component which was not working because I had to parent an empty object to all of the body parts and that object didn't have a sprite.

Comment: @Kevin The second way is to add a bool called `facingRight` (which I'm using right now). The only reason why I want to change the value from float to Vector2 is for `movementInput.x`. If I keep `movementInput` as a `float`, then I get an error because the float doesn't contain a definition for `x` and the only way is replacing it with a `Vector2`. I don't know any other way but  if you know a way that is easier,  please tell me and I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code.

1. In your Update you declare a second local movementInput Vector2. This one hides your movementInput in your class and while no errors are produced, your Flip() won't work. Delete the Vector2 in front of movementInput.
2. Your actionMap looks wrong. Your action needs to be of the type Value with ControlType Vector2. Next you are missing the Composite 2D Vector for your input. It should look like this

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

> The only reason why I want to change the value from float to Vector2 is for `movementInput.x`. If I keep movementInput as a float, then I get an error because the float doesn't contain a definition for x

Yes, a float doesn't have an `x` property because it's a single numeric value. The `x` property of Vector2 *is* a float. It sounds like you need to brush up on your basic data structures like floats and Vectors.

What you need is this:

```
private float movementInput;

void FixedUpdate() {    
    if(facingRight == false && movementInput > 0){       
        Flip();
    } else if (facingRight == true && movementInput < 0){        
        Flip();    
    }
}

void Update() {
    movementInput = playerActionControls.Land.Move.ReadValue<float>();
       
    transform.Translate(movementInput * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried the other answer and it solved my problem. The player can now move, jump and flip.

Comment: The only thing that should be fixed is `transform.Translate` because it makes a vibrating effect when the player collides with the wall and sometimes it moves slightly to the right or the left. I might ask another question about this. Thank you for everything!

Comment: @Ali That's probably physics correcting your movement. Basically you are pushing your character into the wall with the movement code and the physics engine is pushing him/her out with it's own code. To get around that just raycast in the direction you want to move and stop them before going into the next collider or make the physics engine handle movement by either calling rigidBody.MovePosition(nextPosition) (only works on non-kinematic rigidbodies) or using rigidBody.velocity = movementdirection * speed;

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson I want to use `rb.MovePosition` but I'm not sure what position (parameter) I should pass into it and what variables I need to add before this. Could you please tell me the exact code that I have to write, based on the player controller above?

Comment: @Ali I don't really have time to check but I would guess it is something like rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (speed * Time.deltaTime * movementInput)); There maybe a boolean flag as well to specify if the position is global or local but I don't really know of the top of my head. Anyway I believe it will work if you replace your transform.Translate line with that but without testing I'm not really sure.